# How to select the rows of first occurrences of a list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'CompanyID': np.random.choice(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],50),
               'Date': np.random.choice(pd.Series(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='D', periods=180)), 50),
               'Credits': np.random.uniform(0,1000,50),
               'Amount': np.random.uniform(0, 1000, 50),
              }, columns=['Date', 'CompanyID', 'Credits', 'Amount'])
sample = sample.sort_values('CompanyID')
sample['Days'] = sample.Date.diff().map(lambda x: abs(x.days))
sample
```

I'm trying to find the amount of days between each purchase of a package of credits for each company. However, the most recent row of each company needs to have a `Days` value of `NaN`, not the value of the datedifference between the most recent package bought for the company and the oldest package bought from the company right above in the dataframe.

My question: How do I locate the rows in this dataframe that are the first occurrence of the CompanyID (preferably being able to pass a list of unique CompanyIDs through) and replace the `Days` value with `NaN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idx = sample.drop_duplicates(subset='CompanyID', keep="first")
sample['Date'][sample.index.isin(list(Idx.index)] = None

Comment: Absolutely brilliant